# Disable HTTPS in Laravell 7

Tags: laravel

How can I disable HTTPS in Laravell 7 so that all CSS, js, and URLs use http instead of https?

Basically, I have migrated hosting to another hosting provider where I have not installed SSL for HTTPS now my site css, js and url not working

Comment: The URLs for your assets will use the same scheme as the website they are loaded on.

Comment: check in `AppServiceProvider` you want to comment `\URL::forceScheme('https');` assumed you have added previously

Comment: HTTPS is free these days, and easy. Install SSL with something like Let's Encrypt?

Answer (score 1):

add `\URL::forceScheme('http');` or `$this->app['request']->server->set('HTTP', true);` to boot() method in `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php`. example:

```
public function boot()
{   
    $this->app['request']->server->set('HTTP', true); 
}
```

and make sure no hard code asset in https, example `<img src="https://urdomain.com/a.jpg"`, if like that you need to replace manually.